# First character should be strictly an alphabet

Tags: vb.net

The first letter of the entered text should be alphabet only and special characters should not be allowed. I am doing project using vb.net. may I know how to do this.

Comment: Unless you have some code that's not working you'd like to show us, take a look at vb.net String functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx .. once you read those you should be able to come up with method to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following accepts only `Characters` in `TextBox`:

Try this code, it will check if the text in your `textbox` matches the `pattern` in the []-brackets (^ will check the first character, `A-Z will only allow uppercase characters`):

**Example 1:**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim textBox As TextBox
    textBox = sender

    If (textBox.Text.Length > 0) Then
       If Not Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, "^[A-Z|a-z]") then
          TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Example 2:**

```
Dim Name As String = txtBox.text 
        If Not Name.Chars(0).IsLetter(Name.Chars(0)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not valid!")
            txtBox.clear() 
            txtBox.focus()
        End If
```

Please make changes as per your requirement.

Comment: In your first example, `textBox.Text.Length > 0 And textBox.Text.Length = 1` is equivalent to `textBox.Text.Length = 1`, and will exclude any text that is greater than 1 character.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, `^[A-Z|a-z]` should handle upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the String functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx

You might also want to have a look at Regular Expressions: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)